# Exporting CLion Projects for use on systems without CMake

Tags: makefile, cmake, clion

I use CLion for my highschool class projects. My tutor uses no specific IDE, but wants us to send him the code + a Makefile for normal Unix systems.
But when I try the produced Makefile on a system without CMake, it asks for CMake. I didn't find a solution in the documentation either.

Comment: If your project is not so big, you can quickly and easily write Makefiles by hand. It's a good exercise

Comment: This appears to be the workaround I'll use, thx.